# Python: cannot import name 'etree' from 'lxml'

Tags: python, html, lxml

I am trying to import html as lxml, i have tried to uninstall and install, without luck, i keep getting the following error:

```
File "C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\site-packages\lxml\html\__init__.py", line 53, in <module>
    from .. import etree

ImportError: cannot import name 'etree' from 'lxml' (C:\devtools\Python3\Lib\site-packages\lxml\__init__.py)
```

Uninstalling, installing different version

Answer (score 1):

just use the below command
pip install lxml-4.6.3-cp38-cp38-win_amd64

or install another version of lxml

pip install lxml==3.6.0